# cannot find static library using MinGW g++ on windows

Tags: windows, g++, mingw, static-libraries

I'm using a static library called libevent.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "event2/event.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    event_base_new();
    cout<<"hello"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This is just used to test if it's working or not.

I have compiled the library on Mac OS , Ubuntu and Windows. When I compile the code on Mac OS and Ubuntu using `g++ -o main main.cpp -I include/ -L lib/ -levent_core` , everything is fine. But when it comes to Windows, the compiler cannot find the library. I have tried the cmd below:

- `g++ -o main main.cpp -I include/ -L lib/ -levent_core`
- `g++ -I include/ -L lib/ -levent_core -o main main.cpp`
- `g++ -I ./include/ -L ./lib/ -levent_core -o main main.cpp`

and they all got the error says

> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   cannot find -levent_core collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit
>   status

I'm sure the library is correct because I can compile the code using Visual Studio 2013. (I choose the platform to be Win32 so I think the library is 32 bit version)

I'm using mingw32 3.21 on Windows7 64bit

`g++ --version` shows

```
g++.exe (GCC) 4.9.3
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

When I try to build the code using CMake, still success on Mac and Ubuntu and fail on Windows with same error. I do this again on another Windows7 PC but still not working.

Comment: Is the library named **libevent_core**?

Comment: @Joel yes，it's libevent_core.lib, so I think -levent is right

Comment: mingw use "A" for shared libraries extensions in windows. So you might need to compile that library in windows. But, I succesfully link a .lib library using gcc 4.9.2. Maybe there are other things there that make you unable to link.

Comment: @Joel The library is compiled as a static library and can be linked by Visual Studio so I don't think it's the library's problem, but I will try a simple hello world static library later to see if it's working. Thanks